# How do I set a fix max and min value for a chart in JFreeChart?

Tags: java, charts, jfreechart, linechart, yaxis

I am really new to use JFreeChart and I don't know how to set a fixed value for the y-axis so that when my datasets change the max and min y-axis value are the same.

Here is my code so far:

```
public static DefaultCategoryDataset createDataset()
    {

        dataset = new DefaultCategoryDataset();
        
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[0], "nm", "410");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[1], "nm", "435");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[2], "nm", "460");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[3], "nm", "485");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[4], "nm", "510");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[5], "nm", "535");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[6], "nm", "560");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[7], "nm", "585");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[8], "nm", "610");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[9], "nm", "645");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[10], "nm", "680");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[11], "nm", "705");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[12], "nm", "730");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[13], "nm", "760");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[14], "nm", "810");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[15], "nm", "860");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[16], "nm", "900");
        dataset.addValue(Var.numbers[17], "nm", "940");
        
        return dataset;
    }

public chart()
    {
        lineChart = ChartFactory.createLineChart("LineChart", "nm","E", LineChart.createDataset(), PlotOrientation.VERTICAL, true,true,false);
        lineChartPanel = new ChartPanel(lineChart);
        lineChartPanel.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(15, 15, 15, 15));
        lineChartPanel.setBackground(Color.white);
        lineChartPanel.setVisible(true);
        gFrame.add(lineChartPanel);
    }
}
```

And this works fine but the y-axis max and min are changing if the dataset change. So how do I set a fix value for those ?

Comment: [mcve] please .. and stick to java naming conventions